# what does this notation mean in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

so I have:

```
char inBuf[80]
```

and then there's another line

```
inBuf+9
```

what does it mean when I add that +9 to the array's name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is same as referencing element number 9(0 based).

An equivalent notation would be:

```
&inBuf[9]
```

If you want to get the value, you could use `*(inBuf+9)`

Comment: It's the 10th element... "9th element (0 based)" is still not correct - ("element number 9 (0 based)" would be).

Answer (score 2):

This would point to the 10th element of the array. So for example:

```
*(inBuf + 9) = 10
```

would assign 10 to the 10th element.

Comment: 10th element... they're 0 based.

Comment: @Tony: What can I say, you are correct. Thx for the down vote this bad answer really deserved it!

Comment: not my down vote... don't sweat it... we'd never get any good answers on S.O. if everyone felt they had to make them perfect first time... :-).

Answer (score 1):

Answer has been given already. I may only be repeating it.

This is called **pointer arithmetic,** because pointers are involved in the arithmetic operation. there are certain things only you can do with pointers. 
like you can add an integer to it, but you can subtract an integer only if pointer points to some array in the memory. 
 also you can not subtract the pointers, because that may lead to some crucial memory location (for the OS).

addition in pointer arithmetic is special in a way that it takes care of the data type of the array elements, so when you say

```
char inBuf[80]
inBuf + 9
```

it advances 9 memory location sufficient enough to hold the 9 character (9*1 bytes typically)

```
int inBuf[80]
inBuf + 9
```

this will add 9 memory location sufficient enough to hold the 9 integers (9*4 bytes typically).

**array and pointers are not always same, refer to "expert C programming" for that 
Also never use pointer arithmetic polymorphic-ally, refer "scott meyers book" for that**

Answer (score 0):

inBuf is like to write &inBuf[0].
So inBuf +9 means address of inBuf added with 9 chars length (&inBuf[9]).

Comment: what's the uncommented -1 reason?

Comment: Wasn't me.  While I can understand where you're coming from, I can also understand why someone might have downvoted: technically `inBuf` can decay to a pointer, but doesn't do so unless useful.  There are things you can do with `inBuf` - most notably bind to a `const` reference to an array with templated size - that you can't do to `&inBuf[0]`.

Comment: Also, "9 chars length word" is wrong: a "word", when discussing memory addresses, is a unit of memory related to the native register size on the CPU and/or CPU<->memory transfer width: typically 32 or 64 bits these days, whereas `char` is typically 8 bits.  Perhaps "9 `char`'s length" would have been better.

Comment: @Tony: thanks for your comment. I'm always pleased to be corrected. I removed word that was clearly a wrong term (I wrote it fast without thinking too much). For what concerning inBuf I was thinking that speaking about addresses was more understandable in term of adding 9 char, because what you are really doing is referencing a pointer to &inBuf + (9 * sizeof(char)).

Answer (score 0):

Using inBuf with no qualifier for an array index to use will be the same as seeing char *inBuf.  inBuf + 9 would be the same as inBuf[9].

Answer (score 0):

inBuf+9 means increasing the address of inBuf by 9.

Answer (score 0):

inBuf refer the base address. but inBuf+ 9 locates the 10th element from the base address.

```
   *(inBuf + 9) = 34;
```

This would assign the value 34 to the 10th element in the inBuf array.

Comment: 10th element... they're 0 based.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform addition with it, an array identifier such as your `inBuf` decays to a pointer to the first element in the array, and the number added is multiplied by the size of the array element (in this case char, which has size 1) to produce a new address.

So, `inBuf + 9` is the address of the 10th element in the array, which could also be expressed as `&inBuf[9]`.  You can use it as in:

```
*(inBuf + 9) = '\0';   // overwrite the 10th element in inBuf with a NUL
const char* p = strchr(inBuf + 9, ' ');  // find space at or beyond 10th char
```